# What is the sovereign account of the relay chain?

Tags: xcm

What is the sovereign account of a relay chain on a parachain? This can be useful for  e.g. funding the account for xcm execution fee payment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to Asset Hub's configuration to convert the multi location of the relay chain (`parent: 1, interior: Here`) to a native account id, [`ParentIsPreset`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/bf90cb0b73a2d2e0b3e79b2956256831ae79c9f7/cumulus/parachains/runtimes/assets/asset-hub-polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L65) is provided by the `xcm-builder`, the encoding is done via [(ref)](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/bf90cb0b73a2d2e0b3e79b2956256831ae79c9f7/polkadot/xcm/xcm-builder/src/location_conversion.rs#L273-L286):

```
Some(
    b"Parent"
        .using_encoded(|b| AccountId::decode(&mut TrailingZeroInput::new(b)))
        .expect("infinite length input; no invalid inputs for type; qed"),
)
```

This is commonly used by parachains as far as I know, but otherwise look for the [`LocationToAccountId`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/bf90cb0b73a2d2e0b3e79b2956256831ae79c9f7/cumulus/parachains/runtimes/assets/asset-hub-polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L63-L65) => something that converts the `MultiLocation` of the relay chain to an `AccountId`.

Resulting into the AccountId: **5Dt6dpkWPwLaH4BBCKJwjiWrFVAGyYk3tLUabvyn4v7KtESG**